# angular service not being called in .then()

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am having problem calling my $apartments service within this controller.

```
$scope.checkout = () => {
$scope.stripe_err = null;

if ($scope.subscription.type === '') {
  $scope.stripe_err = 'No subscription selected';
  return;
}

Stripe.card.createToken($scope.stripeToken, stripeResponse);
}
let stripeReponse = (status, response) => {
if (status !== 200) {
  $scope.stripe_err = status;
  return;
} else {
  $stripe.checkout(token, response.id)
    .then((result) => {
      $scope.receipt = result.data.receipt / 100; // Stripe amount is in cents
      $scope.totalPrice = '';
      $scope.stripeToken = { number: '', cvc: '', exp_month: '', exp_year: '' };
    })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
  $apartments.postApt(token, $scope.userInfo); // The request finishes when my services is outside the .then()
};
```

but when I replace the parameters with the wrong one `$apartments.postApt(result, $scope.userInfo);`
then I get this error `PUT http://localhost:7000/landlord-api/units/[object%20Object]?access_token=[object%20Object] 500 (Internal Server Error)`

This is how my $apartments service looks like. I'm not sure if its my service because if I call it outside of `$stripe.checkout()` it will get invoke.

```
exports.$apartments = function ($http, $q) {
  function postApt (landlord_id, newApt) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.put('/landlord-api/units/' + landlord_id + '?access_token=' + landlord_id, newApt)
      .then(function (result) {
        return deferred.resolve(result);
      })
      .catch(err => deferred.reject(err));
    return deferred.promise;

  return {
    postApt: postApt
   }
 }
```

UPDATE: I still haven't solved it. What I noticed is if I put my $apartments service in `.then()` the request just stays pending, but if I put it outside the `.then()` it finishes the request and I get the appropriate response.

Comment: Why are you naming your services with a `$`?! Generally the `$` is reserved for framework objects.

Comment: You're right. Maybe i should change that to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Check your landlord_id, look at the response, you are sending an object:

```
access_token=[object%20Object]
```

Make a console.log of landlord_id so you get the structure. 
A common posibility is that it is an array.

Comment: Yes. I get an array when I intentionally pass in the result object, but when I pass in my token I get the actual token. I waited for a while and I got this `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. If I put the service outside the promise chain it get invoked without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this .

```
exports.$apartments = function ($http, $q) {
 function postApt (landlord_id, newApt) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   angular.element(document.getElementById("YOUR_FORM_ID")).scope().getlandlord.then  
     (function (result)){
       return deferred.resolve(result);
     }).catch(err => deferred.reject(err));
  return deferred.promise;
 return {
postApt: postApt
 }
}

scope.getlandlord(landlord_id,newApt){
    return $http.post('/landlord-api/units/' + landlord_id + '?access_token=' + landlord_id, newApt).then(function(response) {
        return response;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem probably exists here:

```
$stripe.checkout(token, response.id)
  .then((result) => {
    // your stuff
  })
  .then((result) => {
    // your stuff
  })
  .catch((err) => { });
```

Remove the first .then() and see if you get the $result.data.success logic working in the second (now only) .then()